# Greater than X but less than Y javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new here, but i'm simply trying to figure out why this javascript is not working in my math program.

For the last two IF statements, i'm comparing numbers. Greater than X but less than Y...

```
(function(){

if(fieldname4-fieldname3 < 30) return (1));

if ((fieldname4-fieldname3 > 31) && (fieldname4-fieldname3 < 60)) return 
(2);


if ((fieldname4-fieldname3 > 60) && (fieldname4-fieldname3 < 90)) return 
(3);


})();
```

Thanks for any help you can give me.

EDIT: I'm going to post the full script when i'm back to my compuer. Sorry for being so vague. It wasn't intentional. I'm still learning.

Comment: Question: what should your code return if `fieldname4-fieldname3` is *exactly* 30?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I should put an = in there, eh?

Comment: What are the values of `fieldname4` and `fieldname3` when the code fails?

Comment: @4castle - None

Comment: where is the return value going?

Comment: What "does not work"? What values of `fieldname3` and `fieldname4` do lead to an unexpected result, and what would you have expected instead?

Comment: @Ryan None as in `undefined`? I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Hard for anyone to help without a [mcve]

Comment: You have an extra `)` after the first `if` statement

Comment: You should put an `<=` there. Feel free to lose the parentheses around your return values as well. By the way, if you don't have any values assigned, what did you expect to happen really?

Comment: @4castle - Yes, undefined.

Comment: I should post the full script - Sorry for being so vague. I'm still learning.

Comment: Undefined is *not* the same as *0*. That sums up your question really.

Comment: Sorry @MilanVelebit

Comment: @Ryan No need to be, just be sure to read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and welcome to the community.

Comment: There are problems with the code, but I don't think the question fails MCVE per se

Answer (score 0):

You can try to write a better code. For example:

```
(function(){
    if(fieldname4-fieldname3 < 30){
        return 1; //returns 1 for every number smaller then 30
    }
    if(fieldname4-fieldname3 >= 30 && fieldname4-fieldname3 <= 60){
        return 2; // returns 2 for every number smaller then 60(includes 60) and greater then 30(includes 30)
    }
    if(fieldname4-fieldname3 > 60 && fieldname4-fieldname3 < 90){
        return 3; // returns 3 for number smaller then 90 and greater then 60
    }
})();
```

I hope that this will help you

Answer (score 0):

Just shooting at it in the dark without seeing the script but how about this??

```
function test (fieldname4, fieldname3) {

  var fieldResult = fieldname4 - fieldname3;

  if(fieldResult < 30) {
    return 1;
  } else if ((fieldResult > 31) && (fieldResult < 60)) {
    return 2;
  } else if ((fieldResult > 60) && (fieldResult < 90)) {
    return 3;
  }    
};
```